# PDO / mySQL How to bind multiple values to store multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

To store 6 invoce items from a website through a `form method="post"`, I use several input elements like this

```
    <input name="item[]" value="6 hour service"/>
    <input name="item[]" value="1 days travel"/>
....
```

Serverside I copy $_POST['Item'] to an array like this

```
item[]= $_POST['Item'];
```

Then I can access item[] and it looks like this

```
[item] => Array
    ( 
       [0] => 6 hour service
       [1] => 1 days travel
       [2] => ....
    )
```

Then this SQL statement follows

```
try {
    $obj = $this->dbcon->prepare('INSERT INTO invoice_item 
                 ( ID, item) 
           VALUES(:ID,:item)');

            for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++) {

            if (!empty($item[0][$i])) {
                $obj->bindValue(':ID', $this->dbcon->lastInsertId(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $obj->bindValue(':item', $item[0][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $succ = $obj->execute();
                }
            }
    }

    catch(PDOException $e)  {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

This works fine for a fix amount of items.
But what is the correct way to access $_POST, bind it and to store it when the amount of items are not known ?

EDIT :

How to iterate over $_POST["Item"] directly ?

Comment: ->lastInsertId() is from a previous table I need to refer to later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `$i` is less than the number of items rather than less than a fixed value.

```
        for ($i=0;$i<count($item[0]);$i++) {

        if (!empty($item[0][$i])) {
```

alternatively you could use `foreach`:

```
        foreach ($item[0] as $value) {

        if (!empty($value)) {
```

Comment: Great -  Is it also possible to access $_POST[item] directly instead making a temp item[] copy ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to iterate over `$_POST["Item"]` directly too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to necessarily bind the ID, because it become from the db itself. Then, you can use an unique query.

Get the ID:

```
$id = $this->dbcon->lastInsertId();
```

Filter `$_POST['Item']` to discard empty values:

```
$items = array_values( array_filter( $_POST['Item'] ) );
```

Create a string with your query:

```
$query = substr( "INSERT INTO invoice_item (ID, item) VALUES " . str_repeat( "($id, ?),", count($items) ), 0, -1);
```

Assuming a `$_POST['Items']` with three not-empty values and `id` = 3, now `$query` is:

```
INSERT INTO invoice_item (ID, item) VALUES (3, ?),(3, ?),(3, ?)
```

Now you can prepare the query and executing it binding all parameters at once (using an array as `->execute` argument, parameters are bind as strings):

```
$obj = $this->dbcon->prepare( $query );
$obj->execute( $items );
```

Comment: Hm, this is  new to me, I have to check and come back on this  ;-)

Comment: Great it works, looks effecient. There are 2 more colums to feed with `fee` and `date`. How to integrate them ?